# Saving Data Stored In viewpart in RCP application

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

I am using saveState method of viewPart to save my view state.Below is my code for saving data in my viewPart.

```
package view;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.TableEditor;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.ui.IMemento;
import org.eclipse.ui.IViewSite;
import org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;

import tutogef.model.Connection;
import tutogef.model.Node;
import tutogef.model.Service;
import tutogef.xml.ThreatTypeXMLToObject;

public class Theartview extends ViewPart implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3033215443267698138L;
    public static String ID = "TutoGEF.theartview_id";
    public static String ID1 = "TutoGEF.theartview_id1";
    private Table table;
    private String Theart_Name;
    private String Category_Name;
    private String Status_Name;
    private String Priority_Name;
    private String Descrption_Name;
    private String Justification_Name;
    private static Node sourceNode;
    private static Node targetNode;
    private static String connectionType;
    private String shortDescription;
    private String category;
    private String description;
    private ThreatTypeXMLToObject threattypexmltoobject;
    private Connection conn;
    private Text text_1, text_2, text_3, text_4;
    private ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private HashMap<Integer, String> list2 = new HashMap<>();
    // HashMap<Integer, String> list3 = new HashMap<>();
    private static Integer a = 0;
    private IMemento memento;
//  String Key = "Key";
//  String Key1 = "Key1";
//  String Key2 = "Key2";
//  String Key3 = "Key3";
//  String Key4 = "Key4";
//  String Key5 = "Key5";
//  String Key6 = "Key6";
    String[] keyValues = { "KeyValue1", "KeyValue2", "KeyValue3", "KeyValue4",
            "KeyValue5", "KeyValue6" };

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void getDataOfConnection(Node sourceNode, Node targetNode,
            String connectionType1) {
        this.sourceNode = sourceNode;
        this.targetNode = targetNode;
        this.connectionType = connectionType1;

    }

    public Theartview() {
    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

        parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, false));

        table = new Table(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 10, 1));
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);

        String[] titles = { "Theart Name", "Category", "Satus", "Priority",
                "Description", "Justification" };
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
            column.setWidth(150);
            column.setText(titles[i]);
        }

        if (memento != null) {
            System.out.println("Entering Restore State");
            restoreState(memento);
        }
        memento = null;
    }

    void restoreState(IMemento memento) {
        System.out.println("Restore State Entered");

        IMemento[] mems = memento.getChildren(ID1);
        System.out.println(mems);
        for (int q = 0; q < mems.length; q+=3) {
            System.out.println("Enter: -----------------------------");
             IMemento mem = mems[q];

             System.out.println(mems.length);
             System.out.println(q);
             System.out.println(mem);
            TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);

            // for Theart_Name
            TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(table);

            Text text = new Text(table, SWT.NONE);
            editor.grabHorizontal = true;
            editor.setEditor(text, item, 0);
            text.setText(mem.getString(keyValues[q]));
            Theart_Name = text.getText().toString().trim();

            // For Category_Name
            editor = new TableEditor(table);
            text = new Text(table, SWT.NONE);
            editor.grabHorizontal = true;
            editor.setEditor(text, item, 1);
            text.setText(mem.getString(keyValues[q + 1]));
            Category_Name = text.getText().toString().trim();

            // For Status_Name
            editor = new TableEditor(table);
            final Combo Status_Combo = new Combo(table, SWT.READ_ONLY);
            Status_Combo.add("Mitigated");
            Status_Combo.add("Not Applicable");
            Status_Combo.add("Not Started");
            Status_Combo.add("Needs Investigation");
            editor.grabHorizontal = true;
            editor.setEditor(Status_Combo, item, 2);

            Status_Combo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(Status_Combo.getText());
                    Status_Name = Status_Combo.getText();
                }

                public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(Status_Combo.getText());
                    Status_Name = Status_Combo.getText();
                }
            });

            // For Priority_Name
            editor = new TableEditor(table);
            final Combo priority_Combo = new Combo(table, SWT.NONE);
            priority_Combo.add("High");
            priority_Combo.add("Medium");
            priority_Combo.add("Low");
            editor.grabHorizontal = true;
            editor.setEditor(priority_Combo, item, 3);

            priority_Combo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(priority_Combo.getText());
                    Priority_Name = priority_Combo.getText();
                }

                public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(priority_Combo.getText());
                    Priority_Name = priority_Combo.getText();
                }
            });

            // For Descrption_Name
            editor = new TableEditor(table);
            text = new Text(table, SWT.NONE);
            editor.grabHorizontal = true;
            editor.setEditor(text, item, 4);
            text.setText(mem.getString(keyValues[q + 2]));
            Descrption_Name = text.getText().toString().trim();

            // For justification
            editor = new TableEditor(table);
            text = new Text(table, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP
                    | SWT.V_SCROLL);
            editor.grabHorizontal = true;
            editor.setEditor(text, item, 5);
            Justification_Name = text.getText().toString().trim();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void fillTableRoWData() {
        if (Connection.Number_Of_Connection != 0) {
            // item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
            if (Service.class.isInstance(sourceNode)) {
                String id = "S1";
                shortDescription = threattypexmltoobject.shortdescription(id,
                        sourceNode.getName(), targetNode.getName(), null);

                category = "Spoofing";
                description = threattypexmltoobject.longdescription(id,
                        sourceNode.getName(), targetNode.getName(), null);

                fillRows(shortDescription, category, description);
            }

            if (Service.class.isInstance(sourceNode)
                    && (connectionType == Connection.CONNECTION_DESIGN)) {
                String id = "T1";

                System.out.println(conn.getConnectionDesign());

                shortDescription = threattypexmltoobject.shortdescription(id,
                        sourceNode.getName(), targetNode.getName(),
                        conn.getConnectionDesign());
                category = "Tampering";
                description = threattypexmltoobject.longdescription(id,
                        sourceNode.getName(), targetNode.getName(),
                        conn.getConnectionDesign());
                fillRows(shortDescription, category, description);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Hash Map" + list2);
        System.out.println("List : []" + list1);
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {

    }

    private void fillRows(String shortdesc, String categ, String descp) {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);

        // for Threat_Name
        TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(table);

        text_1 = new Text(table, SWT.NONE);
        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.setEditor(text_1, item, 0);
        text_1.setText(shortdesc);

        text_1.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {

            @Override
            public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Modify Text");
                Text text = (Text) e.widget;
                System.out.println(text.getText());
            }
        });
        Theart_Name = text_1.getText().toString().trim();
        list1.add(Theart_Name);
        list2.put(a, Theart_Name);

        // For Category_Name
        editor = new TableEditor(table);
        text_2 = new Text(table, SWT.NONE);
        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.setEditor(text_2, item, 1);
        text_2.setText(categ);
        Category_Name = text_2.getText().toString().trim();
        list1.add(Category_Name);
        list2.put(++a, Category_Name);

        // For Status_Name
        editor = new TableEditor(table);
        final Combo Status_Combo = new Combo(table, SWT.READ_ONLY);
        Status_Combo.add("Mitigated");
        Status_Combo.add("Not Applicable");
        Status_Combo.add("Not Started");
        Status_Combo.add("Needs Investigation");
        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.setEditor(Status_Combo, item, 2);

        Status_Combo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(Status_Combo.getText());
                Status_Name = Status_Combo.getText();
                list1.add(Status_Name);
                list2.put(++a, Status_Name);
            }

            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(Status_Combo.getText());
                Status_Name = Status_Combo.getText();
            }
        });

        // For Priority_Name
        editor = new TableEditor(table);
        final Combo priority_Combo = new Combo(table, SWT.NONE);
        priority_Combo.add("High");
        priority_Combo.add("Medium");
        priority_Combo.add("Low");
        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.setEditor(priority_Combo, item, 3);

        priority_Combo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(priority_Combo.getText());
                Priority_Name = priority_Combo.getText();
                list1.add(Priority_Name);
                list2.put(++a, Priority_Name);
            }

            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(priority_Combo.getText());
                Priority_Name = priority_Combo.getText();
            }
        });

        // For Descrption_Name
        editor = new TableEditor(table);
        text_3 = new Text(table, SWT.NONE);
        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.setEditor(text_3, item, 4);
        text_3.setText(descp);
        Descrption_Name = text_3.getText().toString().trim();
        list1.add(Descrption_Name);
        list2.put(++a, Descrption_Name);

        // For justification
        editor = new TableEditor(table);
        text_4 = new Text(table, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP
                | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.setEditor(text_4, item, 5);
        Justification_Name = text_4.getText().toString().trim();
        list1.add(Justification_Name);
        list2.put(++a, Justification_Name);

    }

    @Override
    public void saveState(IMemento memento) {
        super.saveState(memento);
        System.out.println("Save State Called");

        IMemento mem = memento.createChild(ID1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            mem.putString(keyValues[i], list2.get(i));
            System.out.println("Hash Map Values: [" + i + "] " + list2.get(i));
            System.out.println(mem);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(IViewSite site, IMemento memento) throws PartInitException {
        super.init(site, memento);
        this.memento = memento;
        System.out.println("Intialize the view");

    }
}
```

Following problem occurs

1) When memento is initialized for the first time the code works properly. But when I open up my viewPart again without changing any data the error occurs.

2) I have stored all my values in hashmap. When I restore data I only get the first 3 values rest of the values does not appear. If I use numbers than all the data comes properly. Any solutions for that?

3) In my fillTableRoWData() method when the two if conditions are executed all my listeners stand at the second conditions only. How to move the listeners between two if conditions.

Comment: There is far too much code here. Exactly what do you want to save?

Comment: @greg-449  I have made an edit. I want to store the data that is being displayed when getTable method is called. How can I save it using savestate method. I am not getting any data saved in my viewpart.

Comment: Well were is your code doing the save in the `saveState` method? It is up to you to write this code.

Comment: @greg-449 I have added my savestate and restorestate method. Still the data appears the first time I fire up my view. But if I fire it up again without making any changes than it shows error. And also only half of the data appears in the viewPart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.elementFactories` extension point and implement the `createElement` method of the `IElementFactory` interface which takes an `IMemento` object.

If you want to make the view `Saveable` then make the viewpart implement `ISaveablePart`